# Why isn't the link processed in this comment?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

At [The concept of duality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73711/the-concept-of-duality#comment648238_73711), it looks like the link in the comment is perfectly well formed.  Why isn't it parsed as a link?
[image: Link in comment isn't parsed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a space between the `[link text]` and the `(link itself)`. This is visible in e.g. [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1359971?opt.textResults=true):

[image]